# Simple image server

Tags: python, http, image

I have a bunch of images that I need others to browse via a web browser in pretty much the same way as [Apache-Gallery](http://search.cpan.org/~legart/Apache-Gallery-1.0RC3/lib/Apache/Gallery.pm).

I'd be able to dump all my images in a directory so that users hitting:

http://server:port/directory

would see small thumbnails and selecting an image would load it full size on a page with options to browse the previous or next image.

I'm looking for a non Apache solution, much like the wonderfull Python simple http server, that can be launched anywhere with minimal configuration & fuss e.g.

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

In fact, the python solution above is pretty much want I want except it doesn't thumbnail the images but just a simple directory listing.

Happy to use an app written in any common language so long as it is self contained and can run on linux on a custom port (and to re-iterate, not an Apache module).

**UPDATE**

I just found a python script called **[curator](http://furius.ca/curator/)** which is simple to run. It generates the required thumbs and static html from any images in the directory you point it at, after which you can use the SimpleHttpServer to vend the results.

Comment: SimpleHTTPRequestHandler is a very simple class, you can just tweak it to add thumbnails, and you can also generate thumbnails on the fly using PIL

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Curator seems to do all I need for now though...

Comment: @AnuragUniyal How would you tweak it? I'd like to try it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the answers and comments. The solution I ended up using was as per my update:

1. Run [`curator`](http://furius.ca/curator/) in the directory containing all my images. This generates thumbs and an index page, as well as pagination to all the full sized images.
2. Run  "*`*python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000*`*" in that directory to browse the resultant html generated by curator

So this is a simple two step process that pretty much satisfies my initial requirements.

Comment: This worked great until it tried to interpret gifs as jpegs in the thumbnail generation process. When I get the spare time at some point I'll see if I can fix this package somehow.

Answer (score 14):

This was all quite a long time ago now, but I've just begun [imageMe](http://www.imageme.xyz/), which aims to fulfil exactly this need. You can set it up with the instructions on the site, but if you just want to serve a basic gallery of the images in and below your current location, this command will run it on port 8000:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unwitting/imageme/master/imageme.py | python
```

Hopefully that helps anyone else coming along to have this question answered!

Comment: The link is, unfortunately, broken.

Answer (score 4):

Although it doesnt use the SimpleHTTPServer class, this cgi-bin script shows how to display images in a very simply way. Extend it to fit your needs. [Source is here.](http://lost-theory.org/python/randomimg.html)

```
from os import listdir
from random import choice

ext2conttype = {"jpg": "image/jpeg",
                "jpeg": "image/jpeg",
                "png": "image/png",
                "gif": "image/gif"}

def content_type(filename):
    return ext2conttype[filename[filename.rfind(".")+1:].lower()]

def isimage(filename):
    """true if the filename's extension is in the content-type lookup"""
    filename = filename.lower()
    return filename[filename.rfind(".")+1:] in ext2conttype

def random_file(dir):
    """returns the filename of a randomly chosen image in dir"""
    images = [f for f in listdir(dir) if isimage(f)]
    return choice(images)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dir = "c:\\python\\random_img\\"
    r = random_file(dir)
    print "Content-type: %s\n" % (content_type(r))
    print file(dir+r, "rb").read()
```